# How to change Iframe width inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an Iframe inside a webpage that contains a child Iframe . I want to change child iframe width using jquery . 
Note that inner iframe doesnt have id. 
how can i do that ?
(both iframes are from my domain)

Thankyou very much

```
<Iframe id="iframeDoc ">
   // some codes
  <Iframe>
   // another page codes

  </Iframe>
</Iframe>
```

I have tried these codes but no one did work!

```
$('#iframeDoc > iframe').width("400px");

$('#iframeDoc iframe').width("400px");

$('#iframeDoc').contents().find("iframe").width("400px");
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure too?

Comment: The first step in dealing with iframes is to *get rid of them*. Not only you have one iframe, in fact you have *nested* iframes!

Comment: @Derek: Its part of a cms i need to change !

Comment: Have you tried to lowercase your "Iframe" tags to "iframe" ones ?

Comment: @3Dos: yes they are all in lower case

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) to select the nested iframe:

```
let pageiFrame = document.getElementById('iframeDoc')
let nestediFrame = pageiFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementBySelector('iframe')

pageiFrame.style.width = '400px'
nestediFrame.style.width = '400px'
```

Comment: thankyou #iframeDoc doesnt work and seems to be changed to iframeDoc. pageiFrame.style.width  works fine but the next line seems to have error and javascript doesnt run!

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe lies on a different domain - this can be useful.

Try to look into `Window.postMessage()` method. You can use it inside your iframe and `window.addEventListener('message', messageHandlerFn)`outside.

But it suitable only in case when you have possibility to modify sources outside iframe.